# When I submits form data in redux saga Sometimes it returns success and sometimes it doesn't

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

Why "sometimes" return success in redux saga when I submits form data?
It hasn`t always.

this is Modal Component.
Input some info and submit then call dispatch type:ADD_CATEGORY_REQUEST

When input data is entered in the modal window and the button is pressed, the data is sent to the server, a status code is returned, and the alert window is displayed with the returned value. If I block the submit event using `e.preventDefault()`, It works well, but if I don't, sometimes it succeeds and sometimes it doesn't return success (it can't even return failure). What should I do?

```js
function AddCategory(props) {
  const [categoryData, setCategoryData] = useState("");
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const handleSetCategory = (e) => {
    setCategoryData(e.target.value);
    console.log(e.target.value);
  };
  const handleAddCategory = (e) => {
  //When submit form datas call Dispatch
    dispatch({
      type: "ADD_CATEGORY_REQUEST",
      category: categoryData,
    });
  //Preventing the submit event always returns success,
 //but If I don't prevent it, it can or can not return success.
    alert("Add category Done");
    e.preventDefault();
  };
  return (
    <Modal
     //...modal content
      <Modal.Body>
        <div>
          <form onSubmit={handleAddCategory}>
            <input
              onChange={handleSetCategory}
              type="text"
              placeholder="Input Category"
              required
            ></input>
            <button type="submit">Save</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </Modal.Body>
    </Modal>
  );
}
```

--- SAGA

```js
 function addCategoryAPI(category){
   console.log("addCategoryAPI in saga");

   return axios.post(addCategoryURL, {category}, {
   withCredentials:true,
 });

}
   function* addCategory(action) {
      try {
        console.log("addCategory in saga");
        console.log(action.category);
        const result = yield call(addCategoryAPI, action.category);
        
        if (result.status == 200){//server return 200 status
          yield put({type: ADD_CATEGORY_SUCCESS, category: action.category});
  //Preventing submit event this command always call 
  //but If I don't prevent submit event, sometimes return success
          alert("Success")
        }
      } catch (err) {
        yield put ({type: ADD_CATEGORY_FAILURE, err: err});
        console.error(err);
      }
    }
function* watchAddCategory() {
  console.log("watch AddCategory");
  yield takeLatest(ADD_CATEGORY_REQUEST, addCategory);
}
export default function* rootSaga() {
 yield all([
  fork(watchSignUp),
  fork(watchNickNameDoubleCheck),
  fork(watchLogin),
  fork(watchAddCategory),
 ]);
}
```

Here is my Watcher and API.

Answer (score 0):

Redux saga uses `watchers` to watch your `ADD_CATEGORY_REQUEST` dispatch. Would you give us the code of this watcher.

Try to figure out frequency of your success return.

Is it the first one which works and no other afterwards ?

Is it really random your success return ? I don't think so...

Open your browser console and checkout in the same time the Network XHR HTTP call made by redux saga, and check out there is well a call made. Maybe you are waiting a success return, but there was no call made

[image]

Comment: ʻE.preventDefault()`-> If the submit event is blocked, success is returned for all requests. Otherwise, the first request returns no return. No failure or success is returned, and a response to the next second request returns success.
Similarly, failure and success are not returned in the third, success is returned in the fourth. This is repeated.

Comment: Oh, first I found out that I need to block the form tag's submit event to manage the state. However, I still don't know why there is no response to the first request, and I don't know why the response to the second request returns success.